# Is LSystem broken?

Tags: animation-nodes

I Have a very simple question. Is there a way to make LSystem on Animation Nodes to be shown on object mode? My system only is displayed and updates when I enter edit mode.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not broken. Somehow, the blender 2.8x does not show the Mesh (created with AN) which has only edges. So, to work around this is, either use BMesh in the Mesh Object Output node or convert the Mesh into Splines (Curves) using Splines From Edges node.

Comment: I see. Thank you. However, I have noticed that LSystem Node settings doesn'st change anything only angle (and some other whose name I can't remeber right now). Is this an expected behavior?

Comment: It is working fine on my side. Can you pleasse upload a screenshot of your node-tree?